# Getting the monic form of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Is there a function to obtain the monic form of a multivariables polynomial?

My polynomial is:

```
f = -2 x^2 - x^3 - 3 y
```

sorted with a lexicographic order.

The monic polynomial that I want to obtain is the polynomial divided by the coefficient of the monial of the higher rank.

```
f = -2/3 x^2 - 1/3 x^3 - y
```

In other words, polynomials whose leading coefficients are 1 are called monic.

Comment: What does this question mean? What kinds of transformations do you allow?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you give the explicit answer you're looking for, perhaps for a few different examples?

Comment: This does what you want for the example cited: `Expand[f/3]`. Not sure what you are looking for in general.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

```
poly = -2 x^2 - x^3 - 3 y;
f = poly/(Abs[CoefficientList[poly, y]] // Last) // Expand
```

> `-((2 x^2)/3) - x^3/3 - y`

This can be generalized into a function.

```
monic[poly_, var_] := poly/(Abs[CoefficientList[poly, var]] // Last) // Expand
```

Then

```
monic[-2 x^2 - 3 x^3 - 3 x y + 7 y^3, y]
```

> `-((2 x^2)/7) - (3 x^3)/7 - (3 x y)/7 + y^3`

and

```
monic[-2 x^2 - 3 x^3 - 3 x y + 7 y^3, x]
```

> `-((2 x^2)/3) - x^3 - x y + (7 y^3)/3`

Comment: Is Mathematica's ordering total degree? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But, i think that it doesn't work with f = -2 x^2 - x^3 - 3 y + 4*x*y. The coefficient that should be found is 4. The leading power product ordered lexicographically is x*y.

Comment: What makes `x*y` the leading term? (Hint: there is an unstated assumption on the ordering being made.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau in fact, i want to use the lexigraphic order and consequently, i would like to find the coefficient of the leading term with this order.